# listviewselection in a listfragment in a tab

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager, android-listfragment

I have the following problem. I have an app with a viewpager and two tabs. The two tabs are two listfragments. Now I want that if the user selects an item in the first tab, that the 5th  item is selected in the second tab. (the second tab is the translation of text from the first item). My problem is that when i select an item in the first tab, and now switch to the second tab, there is nothing selected. 
When I click something in the first tab I call a function in the Parent activity which calls a function in the second fragment which should select the 5th Item. 
This is the code of the Fragment activity:

```
public class Dailyquran extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {


    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;


    public  ArrayList<Tweet> tweets = new ArrayList<Tweet>(); 
    public  ArrayList<Tweet> tweets2 = new ArrayList<Tweet>(); 
    //private static ArrayList<String> roomList;

    public String a;
    public static int laenge_inhalt;

    public static int selected;

    public static String sure_media;
    public static String vers_media;
    String koran_filename;
    //int tabwahl=0;

    int playstatus=0;
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    MenuItem playMenu;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_dailyquran, menu);
        playMenu = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_play);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle("Daily Quran");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dailyquran);        
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        // set the app icon as an action to go home
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 
        //enable tabs in actionbar
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

     // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

     // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding tab.
        // We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have a reference to the
        // Tab.
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by the adapter.
            // Also specify this Activity object, which implements the TabListener interface, as the
            // listener for when this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this));
        }




          main(); 

    }

    /*  WEITER UNTEN SIND DIE TABSELECTED FUNKTIONEN !!!!
    //@Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

   // @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

   // @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }    
    */

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private FragmentTransaction mCurTransaction = null;

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }


        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
           return POSITION_NONE; //To make notifyDataSetChanged() do something
       }

        @Override      
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
          //  Fragment building_fragment = new BuildingFragment();
            Fragment room_fragment = new RoomFragment();
            Fragment transl_fragment = new TransliterationFragment();

          //  Fragment device_fragment = new DeviceFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();

            switch(i){
            case 0:

                room_fragment.setArguments(args);

                return room_fragment;
            case 1:           

                return transl_fragment;
            case 2:  
            //  args.putInt(RoomFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, i);
            //    room_fragment.setArguments(args);
                return room_fragment;
            default: return null;
            } 
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0: return "a";
                case 1: return "b";
                case 2: return "c";
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
            if (mCurTransaction == null) {
                mCurTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            }
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Fragment fragment = getItem(position);

            if (fragment!=null){
                System.out.println("Fragment Found!");
                mCurTransaction.attach(fragment);
                }


            return fragment;//super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        }


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_play:
                play();
                return true;



            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem switchButton = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_play);     



    }


    public class Tweet {  

        String content;  
        String sure;
        String vers;

}  

    public class Tweet2 {  

        String content;  
        String sure;
        String vers;

}  

public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



//HERE IS THE CODE FOR SELECTING THE SECOND ITEM

public void one_changed()
    {
        TransliterationFragment fragment_meaning = (TransliterationFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myfragment2);                
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Change Selection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 


        fragment_meaning.change_selected(); // do what updates are required   

    }
```

AND THIS IS THE RELEVANT CODE OF THE SECOND FRAGMENT, I can see the string "Hallo" is in the console, so the function is really called, but i the Item isnt selected.

```
public void change_selected()
    {

        System.out.println("Hallo");
        ListView list=getListView();  
        list.setSelection(4);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working now when i add this code in the function on_changed in the parent activity:

```
TransliterationFragment fragment_meaning = (TransliterationFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:"+R.id.pager+":1");      
fragment_meaning.change_selected(); // do what updates are required
```